# Change root scope

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have some issues with directive scopes...

```js
wall.directive('onPaste', function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope :true,
        controller: function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.getUrlInfos = function() {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        firstPost: $scope.firstPost,
                        lastPost: $scope.lastPost
                    },
                    url: '/wall/json/parseUrl.json'
                }).success(function(data){
                    $scope.firstPost = 99;
                    $scope.parseUrl = data; // response data
                    console.log($scope);
                });
            }

        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {

            element.bind("paste", function(event) {
                var element = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var text = $(element).val();
                    urls = findUrls(text);
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.firstPost = 10;
                        scope.getUrlInfos();
                    })
                }, 100);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

When I `console.log($scope);` the variable has all the scope... but as I understand it is a copy of the root scope. Any change to this scope doesn't appear on the screen. How can I return this scope to the root scope?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have a defined root scope,

```
wall.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.firstPost = 1;
    //.....
});
```

In AngularJS, `$scopes` prototypically inherit from their parent scope, all the way up to `$rootScope`. In JavaScript, primitive types are overwritten when a child changes them. So when you set `$scope.firstPost` in one of your controllers, the property on `$rootScope` was never touched, but rather a new visible property was added to the current scope.

So you need to pass the `rootScope` to directive controller,then change from there.

```
wall.directive('onPaste', function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope :true,
        controller: function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
            $scope.getUrlInfos = function() {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        firstPost: $rootScope.firstPost,
                        lastPost: $rootScope.lastPost
                    },
                    url: '/wall/json/parseUrl.json'
                }).success(function(data){
                    $rootScope.firstPost = 99;
                    $rootScope.parseUrl = data; // response data
                    console.log($rootScope);
                });
            }

        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {

            element.bind("paste", function(event) {
                var element = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var text = $(element).val();
                    urls = findUrls(text);
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.firstPost = 10;
                        scope.getUrlInfos();
                    })
                }, 100);
            });
        }
    };
});
```